# Can I execute a contract function by sending a regular transaction to the contract?

Tags: solidity

I'd like to accept regular transactions to a contract and record a mapping address -> value. Is it possible to achieve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
mapping (address => uint) data;
function () payable {
    data[msg.sender] = msg.value;
}
```

I think that would do it, but someone else should verify. The function without a name is the default function and handles any call that is not called on a named function.

Comment: The comma in the `mapping` should be replaced by an arrow `=>`. Also, for the OP to store it he would need to create an associative array.

Answer (score 2):

Improving on Thomas Jay Rush's code (it's now missing the payable modifier [as of 09/2016](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/17922/10138)):

```
mapping (address => uint) data
function () payable {
    data[msg.sender] = msg.value;
}
```