# Reproducing recursive call exploit

Tags: security, attacks, reentrant-attacks

Here's a contract that I want to attack using recursive call:

```
contract Abstract {
    function foobar();
}

contract B {
    uint stateVar;
    function foo(Abstract someAddress){
        someAddress.foobar();
    }
    function bar(uint x) {
        stateVar = x;
    } 
}
```

Here's a malicious contract deployed at some other address:

```
contract MaliciousContract {
    function foobar() {
        //What do I need to put here to make **B.bar(255)** possible?
    }
}
```

From solidity [docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/control-structures.html):

> Any interaction with another contract imposes a potential danger,
>   especially if the source code of the contract is not known in advance.
>   The current contract hands over control to the called contract and
>   that may potentially do just about anything. Even if the called
>   contract inherits from a known parent contract, the inheriting
>   contract is only required to have a correct interface. The
>   implementation of the contract, however, can be completely arbitrary
>   and thus, pose a danger. In addition, be prepared in case it calls
>   into other contracts of your system or even back into the calling
>   contract before the first call returns. This means that the called
>   contract can change state variables of the calling contract via its
>   functions. Write your functions in a way that, for example, calls to
>   external functions happen after any changes to state variables in your
>   contract so your contract is not vulnerable to a recursive call
>   exploit.

What I'm trying to achieve is:

> This means that the called contract can change state variables of the
>   calling contract via its functions.

So, my actions are:

- I call B.foo('maliciousContractAddress');
- ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
contract MaliciousContract {
    function foobar() {
        //What do I need to put here to make **B.bar(255)** possible?
        B(msg.sender).bar(255);
    }
}
```

This is a good example to remind that calling the exploit a ["recursive call" can be misleading](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/6344/42), because the exploit does not call `foo`, it calls `bar`.

Reentrant attacks can use the initial function (`foo`) but it's important to be aware that **re-entrancy can use any `external` or `public` function** (and recall that the default for functions is `public`).

Comment: compiler throws an error `Undeclared identifier B`. I guess it means I need to add an abstract contract to MaliciousContract, right? Something like, `contract B {
 function bar(uint x);
}`.

Comment: Right. (I pasted the whole question code in Solidity Browser so no issue that way.  For quick testing, make it `uint public statevar` to get an accessor.)

Comment: quick question. How did the DAO attacker knew the definition of the calling contract? Was the DAO source code available at the moment?

Comment: Yes, https://github.com/slockit/DAO  Contracts should generally be open source otherwise it's hard for people to trust that it does what it claims to do.

Comment: I've deployed these two contracts and couldn't reproduce the result. `Out of gas` exception was thrown and the state variable wasn't change. Is it the result of some sort of fix? Here's tx https://testnet.etherscan.io/tx/0x9f2939a01d0064a9045ac1af90a8fedfa53285d83b6023b6774abff37f54028d

Comment: Did you try adding more gas to the transaction?  Why only 43268 gas?