# Are the functions in this code missing the payable modifier?

Tags: payable

[These functions are transferring ether](http://hackingdistributed.com/2016/07/13/reentrancy-woes/) between balances, so why aren't they modified with `payable`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those examples date from a version of solidity prior to when the `payable` modifer existed.  I believe it was introduced [in version 0.4.0, released on September 8, 2016](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases/tag/v0.4.0).  The blog post you link to dates from July of 2016